# DISPLAY=:0.0 Could not connect to any X display

Tags: display

I want to run a slideshow on my Pi using the software slide. When I run the command directly on my pi via the connected mouse and keyboard it works fine. But when I try tu run it via SSH (root user) I get an error.

The command I use: `DISPLAY=:0.0 slide -p /home/ftp`

The error I get: `No protocol specified qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :0`

Can anyone tell me what I need to set?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you run it as root when you run it directly? Have you searched the web for that error msg? Does seem to happen to others when logged in remotely as root...

Comment: @Dirk Yes I am logged in as root. I also searched the web, but didn‘t get any results

Comment: So you have worked your way through all of these https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=No+protocol+specified+qt.qpa.screen%3A+QXcbConnection%3A+Could+not+connect+to+display+%3A0&meta=&aq=f&oq=&rlz=1R2GZEZ_en-GB

Comment: @Dirk yes I did read all the results on the first page. I havn‘t found a solution that worked in my case.

Comment: I assume you do have an X server running on your local computer? Do other GUI-Applications work?